# how to access the file in docroot folder when the server has spring mvc web site on root("/")

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a spring mvc project deploy on root path. Then the files folder in docroot are filtered by spring mvc. I tried to add following config, it's not working

```
   <mvc:resources location="/files/" mapping="/files/**"  order="0"/>
```

I want to access the image file in files folder like: localhost:8080/files/image.jpg

web.xml

```
   <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-shiro.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
      <tracking-mode>
        COOKIE
    </tracking-mode>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>




<!--shiro 配置开始 -->

<!-- <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>-->

<filter>  
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>  
    <init-param>   
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>  
        <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
</filter>  

<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping> 

<!--shiro 配置结束 -->
```

update : I have a solution with absolute path:

```
<mvc:resources location="file:/Users/abc/docroot/files/" mapping="/files/**"  order="0"/>
```

Is there any way to get root path in config file by any variable? ie:server.root

Comment: As you mapped the server to `/` and not `/*` it should work even without the `<mvc:resources .../>` line...

Comment: hi @SergeBallesta , I post more code of web.xml